# Identifying Adjacent Pairs and summing Followup

Tags: r

In my code I calculated the sum of a value if region[i] = region[i+1]. I'm interested in extending this code to provide the sum of value if the regions are adjacent to each other.

Example: region[1] = "AXB" region[2] = "CDB"

This would be adjacent as defined "Adjacent 1"  and the value should be summed:

value[i] = value[i] + value[i+1]

Here is my code thus far:

```
 a = c(15,6,10,50)
 region = c("AXB","AXB","CBD","FLR")
 value = c(10,20,15,30)

 df = data.frame(a,region,value)

 Adjacent1 = c("AXB", "CBD")
 Adjacent2 = c("DMN','FLR")

 for (i in 2:length(df$region)) {
 if (region[i-1] == region[i]) {
    df$value[i-1] <- sum(value[c(i-1, i)])
    }
  }
```

I'm looking for this as my output:

```
a    region value leadregion  valueNew
15    AXB    10   AXB           30
6     AXB    20   CBD           35
10    CBD    15                 
50    FLR    30   FLR           30
```

Answer (score 0):

We want to write a function that helps us to identify if `region[i+1]` is either the same as or "adjacent" to `region[i]`.

First, it's easier to define `Adjacent` as a list, so that you can iterate through it (instead of having `Adjacent1`, `Adjacent2`, etc.).

```
Adjacents <- list(
    c("AXB", "CBD"), 
    c("DMN","FLR")
)
```

We write a function to check if `region[i+1]` is either the same as or "adjacent" to `region[i]`:

```
findAdj <- function(region) {
    adj_list <- Adjacents[unlist(lapply(Adjacents, function(x) region %in% x))]
    unique(c(region, unlist(adj_list)))
}
```

`lapply` iterates through the `Adjacents` list to identify the tuples that contain `region`.  So `findAdj` returns both `region` itself plus all "adjacent" regions.

Then we loop through the `df`:

```
df$valueNew <- NA
for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)) {
    if (df$region[i+1] %in% findAdj(df$region[i])) {
        df$valueNew[i] <- sum(df$value[i:(i+1)])
    }
}
```

to get

```
> df
   a region value valueNew
1 15    AXB    10       30
2  6    AXB    20       35
3 10    CBD    15       NA
4 50    FLR    30       NA
```

(Not sure why `valueNew` in the last row of your output is 30.)